# Drag and Drop поле

Tags: javascript, drag-n-drop

как на JS создать Drag and Drop поле с возможностью удаления добавленных файлов? 
JS не знаю совсем. Я так понимаю файлы из формы нужно сгрузить в массив, id файла -> номер массива. Создать массив по выводу html кода с id и именами наших файлов и кнопочку поместить, для удаления нашего файла из формы.

Comment: может тогда стоит выучить javascript ?или воспользоваться услугами фрилансеров

Comment: Логично.А если в двух словах, то я хочу стажером php разработчиком пойти, а дали задание с использованием JS. Серверная часть вопросов не вызывает

Comment: причём php и javascript ? это как врачу дать монтировать балку

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API вот тренеруйтесь а сюда с первыми попытками